# TeamCity Remote Powershell Access Denied Suddenly

Tags: powershell, teamcity, remote-access

Disclaimer: I am not a DevOps guy so please forgive any ignorance. I'm learning this stuff to expand my understanding.

I've enabled remote Powershell on a Windows Server 2019 instance in order to stop/start scheduled tasks during deployment of files from my build server (also Windows Server 2019).

I followed the below steps in an Administrator Powershell as the `Adminstrator` user on the remote server:
 1. Enable `RSRemoting`.
 2. Remove existing listener.
 3. Create self-signed certificate and export to `crt` file.

```
$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertstoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "<subdomain.domain.com>"
```

4. Create listener.
5. Create firewall rules to allow secure PSRemoting and disable unsecure connections.
6. Copy certificate to build server.
7. Import certificate on build server.

From the build server, I've tested the configuration using the following commands in Powershell:

```bsh
$username = 'Administrator'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string '<password here>' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <subdomain.domain.com> -UseSSL -ScriptBlock {whoami} -Credential $cred
```

Which responds nicely with `win-<some stuff>\administrator`. However, when I execute a remote Powersehll command from within a TeamCity build step, I get a big ugly `Connecting to remote server <subdomain.domain.com> failed with the following error message : Access is denied.`.

The weird part is, this worked two days ago and I have several builds that were able to complete all remote operations. From this morning, it's just stopped working - poof!

If I fudge the credentials, I do get an incorrect username/password error so it is definitely reaching the server.

Another interesting find is that if I run

```bsh
[bool](Test-WSMan)
```

on the remote server, I get `True` returned, but if I run the same command with `-ComputerName <subdomain.domain.com>` on the build server, I get
`WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is 
valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits 
access to remote computers within the same local subnet.` returned.
Both the remote host and build server are logged on as the default `Administrator`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research and calling in a few favours, I was advised to tweak the `TeamCity Build Agent` and `TeamCity Server` services. These need to `Log On As` a `User` and not `Local System`. I can't explain how my previous settings worked. The `Access is denied` error I experienced has nothing to do with the Remote Powershell configuration mentioned above.